# Django's nested render_to_response always show content-type

Tags: python, django, templates, view, render

Currently I am trying to create multiple view for one request. For 1 view, I am doing this:

```
return render_to_response(
    "/index/index.html",
    {}
)
```

And now when I try to add a "left" column to index.html, I need to put it on different view (because I need to apply the same technique on other place as well), this is how I do it:

```
leftCol = direct_to_template(request,settings.viewPath + "/columns/left.html",{})
return render_to_response(
    "/index/index.html",
    {
    'leftColumn': leftCol,
    }
```

The code works well, but the output is not what I expected. The leftCol shows the response header at the beginning of it's output:

"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"

How do I remove this header? I've been trying to modify the content_type and mimetype in the parameter but it didn't work.

Comment: the leftCol was using direct_to_template, before it was render_to_response as well. But the result is same.

Comment: read the docs on rendering content: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context another approach could be to use a template tag or include (cirectly at the template level)

Answer (score 4):

That's because `direct_to_template()` returns a `HttpResponse`, not a string. Have you considered using templating functionality, e.g. the `{% include %}` template tag, or writing a template tag of your own?

If you insist on pre-rendering templates in your view and then combining them in your template, render the template yourself, rather than using `direct_to_template()`. e.g.

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import RequestContext

def someview(request):
    leftCol = get_template(settings.viewPath + "/columns/left.html").render(RequestContext(request)
    render_to_response("/index/index.html", {'leftColumn': leftCol})
```

Comment: Yes, a template tag - specifically, an inclusion tag - is the better option.

Answer (score 4):

Use `render_to_string` (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) to get a string back after rendering a template.  Alternatively, you can use an `{% include %}` to include a template in the same context as the current template (but this is still manual).  Even better would be to have a base template that you inherit using `{% extends 'base.html' %}` which will just include common template functionality that you can override at your will using `{% block %}` and enables you to leave out duplicated template content like a left column.

Comment: Up-voted. The was exactly what I needed to render a template tag to my default-handled 404 page. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The 'render_to_response' function returns an HttpResponse object. Instead of returning the object itself, you can return its content attribute to access only the output you want to render.

i.e.

```
response = render_to_response(
    "/index/index.html",
    {
    'leftColumn': leftCol,
    }
return response.content
```